# Configured Gmail for my own website?

Tags: gmail, mx-record

1. I have configured Gmail with my MX Domain record. Now
2. where can handle all users email [Administration URL]
3. Where user can signup @mydomain.com [SignUp URL]

Comment: Belongs on webmasters.SE, voting to migrate there. Although the very first place to look for this IMO is Google's docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://www.google.com/a/**yourdomain.com**/ServiceLogin?service=CPanel
2. https://www.google.com/a/**yourdomain.com**/ServiceLogin?service=mail

Also you could set cname record for email access e.g. email.yourdomain.com for users.
I think users can not sign up, you have to create all accounts. They can only sign in.